# How To Present This

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

The Data

```
Name    Date    Span
Bob     12/11   0700-1530
Sue     12/11   0700-1530
Bob     12/12   0700-1530
Sue     12/12   0700-1530
Bob     12/13   0700-1530
Sue     12/13   0700-1530
Bob     12/14   0700-1530
Sue     12/14   0700-1530
Bob     12/15   0700-1530
Sue     12/15   0700-1530
Sue     12/16   1200-1830
```

How can I present the data as follows, with one row per person?

```
      Sun      Mon         Tue         Wed         Thu         Fri        Sat
     10DEC    11DEC       12DEC       13DEC       14DEC       15DEC      16DEC
Bob         0700-1530   0700-1530   0700-1530   0700-1530   0700-1530
Sue         0700-1530   0700-1530   0700-1530   0700-1530   0700-1530  1200-1830
```

The span might be different on different days for the same person, and there might more or fewer names for any given week.  If I remember right, this is the purpose of 'cross-tab queries,' which Access can do, but I am not to sure in SharePoint.

Comment: I don't see how you can get any idea of what research I have done, simply from the question... That seems a bit hostile, and judgmental, whoever it is who down-voted it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Is this an app that you're building?  If so, is it a web part or an add-in?  Or are you just trying to create some sort of list view?

Comment: I have a list that has schedule events added to it, where a user selected from a drop-down list is added to the Schedule list, with a date, a start time, and an end time.

Comment: I took too long... -- I have a list that has schedule events added to it, where a user who's been selected from a DD-list is added to the Schedule list, with a date, a start time, & an end time.  ..  I then need to show all the events for a given week (Sun to Sat), with one row per person, whether they have 1 or 7 events that wk.  ... But, since there usually will be 5 schedule events/wk for ea. person, I don't want to list that person's name 5x, but just once at the left. ... Then each adjacent cell to the right of a cell is the next row in the list of scheduled events, for that one person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to achieve that out of the box.  What you'd likely need to do is use client side rendering to change the way the view is displayed.  Here is a sample of a js file that changes a view's rendering (doesn't achieve what you're looking for but it's a start).  The customItem function is where you'll define what each cell looks like.  Then you can manipulate the results in the post render.  Hopefully this can get you going down the right path.  This is a good guide for getting started with CSR: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views

```
(function () {
    // Initialize the variable that stores the objects.
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};

    // Assign functions or plain html strings to the templateset objects:
    // header, footer and item.
    overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "<B><#=ctx.ListTitle#></B>" +
        "<hr><ul id='unorderedlist'>";

    // This template is assigned to the CustomItem function.
    overrideCtx.Templates.Item = customItem;
    overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = "</ul>";

    // Set the template to the:
    //  Custom list definition ID
    //  Base view ID
    overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 2;
    overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 10057;

    // Assign a function to handle the
    // PreRender and PostRender events
    overrideCtx.OnPreRender = preRenderHandler;
    overrideCtx.OnPostRender = postRenderHandler;

    // Register the template overrides.
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();

// This function builds the output for the item template.
// It uses the context object to access announcement data.
function customItem(ctx) {

    // Build a listitem entry for every announcement in the list.
    var ret = "<li>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "</li>";
    return ret;
}

// The preRenderHandler attends the OnPreRender event
function preRenderHandler(ctx) {

    // Override the default title with user input.
    ctx.ListTitle = prompt("Type a title", ctx.ListTitle);
}

// The postRenderHandler attends the OnPostRender event
function postRenderHandler(ctx) {

    // You can manipulate the DOM in the postRender event
    var ulObj;
    var i, j;

    ulObj = document.getElementById("unorderedlist");

    // Reverse order the list.
    for (i = 1; i < ulObj.children.length; i++) {
        var x = ulObj.children[i];
        for (j = 1; j < ulObj.children.length; j++) {
            var y = ulObj.children[j];
            if(x.innerText<y.innerText){                  
                ulObj.insertBefore(y, x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: CSR looks really exciting!  Apparently though, it was rolled out with 2013, and I am constrained to 2010. I think I am going to retrieve data, client-side, from a stub, using JSON, and will doctor up the DOM elements with what comes back.

Comment: Doh! My bad. It is really cool. You can do some interesting things with it. Since you're in SP2010, you're either building a webpart or possibly using a dataview webpart with some xslt to manipulate it. I personally would go the custom webpart route.